# Transform C# Snippet to PHP

Tags: c#, php, transform, translate

can somebody help me to transform this XOR decryption to PHP?

```
public static string DecryptKey(string key)
{
    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
    char[] arr = new char[b.Length];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < b.Length; ii++)
    {
        arr[ii] = (char)(b[ii] ^ 14);
    }

    return new string(arr);

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Variables have the dollar symbol prefix `$key` in PHP. Functions are well documented on http://php.net/

Comment: "can somebody help me" is a terrible euphemism for "i wish for someone else to do this for me". Not sure if the [ŧranslate] tag is to blame though.

Comment: If you want actual help (and not just some one to do it for you) you're going to have to provide the code that you tried and the issue(s) that you are running in to. More information on that can be found in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Right now this is just a very lazy request.

Answer (score 1):

Have it done. Thanks for your help

```
public function DecryptKey($InputString) {
  $InputString = base64_decode($string);
    $retString='';
    for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($InputString); $j++) {
        $retString .= chr(ord(substr($InputString, $j, 1)) ^ 14);
    }
    return $retString;
```

}